# Get started Guide SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, sts

I have downloaded the latest version of spring tool suite (spring-tool-suite-4-4.19.1.RELEASE), when I tried to import spring getting started content, it return as below error:  Get started Guide SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

i tried to imort the proxy certificate but still i face the same issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.